# OnRatingBarChangeListener from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have created a "InterestLine" class with a "lineContent" layout that has a TextView and a RatingBar.
Then I have created an adapter to make a listView of InterestLines on the main layout, so the user can see a list of text views + rating bar besides it, and rate every one of the elements.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener{

private String gender,age,output;
private List<InterestLine> lines;
private Button doneBtn;
private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] interest_list = {"//the list of text views//"};

    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    lines=new ArrayList<InterestLine>();
    for(String il:interest_list)
        lines.add(new InterestLine(il));

    ArrayAdapter<InterestLine> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<InterestLine>(this, R.layout.linecontent, R.id.tv1, lines);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    doneBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // collect stars (interests)
            for(InterestLine il : lines) 
                output = output + il.getInterestName() + ":" + il.getNumberOfStars() + ",";

            Log.i("OUTPUT", output);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I want to onClick of the button to collect all the ratings that were introduced by the user on the RatingBars, tried several methods without success.
Hope you can help me with this.
Thanks

The layout of the main activity:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.86" >
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the layout of the line:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">    
    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/line_text"
        android:id="@+id/tv1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:width="120sp" />
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It'd be cool if you can post your layout as well.

Comment: Check [this](http://animations.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/android-tutorial-74-listview-with-ratingbar.html)

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure it out. For this kind of complex layout, you should not use ArrayAdapter. You should make a custom adapter extend from BaseAdapter.
Here's the working Custom Adapter and Activity codes.

### RatingAdapter

```
public class RatingAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

 List<InterestLine> mInterestLineArrayList;
 private RatingListener ratingListener;
 public RatingAdapter(List<InterestLine> interestLines) {
  mInterestLineArrayList = interestLines;
}

 @Override public int getCount() {
   return mInterestLineArrayList.size();
 }

 @Override public InterestLine getItem(int i) {
   return mInterestLineArrayList.get(i);
 }

 @Override public long getItemId(int i) {
   return i;
 }

 @Override public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)  {
   RatingViewHolder ratingViewHolder;
   if(view==null){
     view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.linecontent,viewGroup,false);
     ratingViewHolder = new RatingViewHolder(view);
     view.setTag(ratingViewHolder);
   }else{
     ratingViewHolder = (RatingViewHolder) view.getTag();
   }
   ratingViewHolder.titleView.setText(getItem(i).getInterestName());
   ratingViewHolder.ratingBar.setNumStars(getItem(i).getNumberOfStars());
   ratingViewHolder.currentPosition = i;
   return view;
 }

 public void setOnItemRatingChangeListener(RatingListener ratingListener){
   this.ratingListener = ratingListener;
 }

 public interface RatingListener{
   void onRatingBarClicked(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b,int position);
 }
 class RatingViewHolder  implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener{
   private TextView titleView;
   private RatingBar ratingBar;
   private int currentPosition;
   public RatingViewHolder(View view){
     titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
     ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
     ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
   }

   @Override public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
     if(ratingListener!=null){
       ratingListener.onRatingBarClicked(ratingBar,v,b,currentPosition);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private String gender, age, output;
private List<InterestLine> lines;
private Button doneBtn;
private ListView lv;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  String[] interest_list = { "Hope","it's","ok" };

  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

  lines = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String il : interest_list) {
    InterestLine interestLine = new InterestLine();
    interestLine.setInterestName(il);
    lines.add(interestLine);
  }

  RatingAdapter adapter = new RatingAdapter(lines);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.setOnItemRatingChangeListener(new RatingAdapter.RatingListener() {
    @Override public void onRatingBarClicked(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b,int position) {
      lines.get(position).setNumberOfStars((int)v);
    }
  });
  doneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
      // collect stars (interests)
      output = "";
      for (InterestLine il : lines) {
        output = il.getInterestName() + " " + il.getNumberOfStars();
        Log.i("OUTPUT", output);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

}

Basically, you create a custom adapter where you can get the instance of each rating bar. Then you set the OnRatingChangeListener on that rating bars. Then you get the desired rating value from the activity with the help of a callback. The tricky part here is getting the item position from the adapter. I solved this by storing the current item position in viewholder. Anyway, I would also like to point out that it will be a lot easier to use recycler view for this kind of thing.